# Procedure to run ubuntu on sony xperia play

Tags: ubuntu-for-android

I want to run ubuntu on my sony xperia play phone but i dont know how to do it so if someone can help regarding it will be highly appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this link and try it once

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1872752